# jquery datatable ajax reload submits the form again

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using jquery datatables to fetch data from server, and then I am also editing this table to add new data. After I added auto-refresh on addition the create request is submitting repeatedly. This is my table

```
var dataTableInitilizationConfig = {
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "aLengthMenu": [20, 50, 100, 200],
    "bJQueryUI":false,
    "bDestroy":true,
    "bProcessing":true,
    "sDom": '<"search-bar"f>rt<"clear">'+ '<"select-bar"l>t<"clear">' +
    '<"bottom-left"i><"bottom-right"p>',
    "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": "",
        "sSearchPlaceholder": "Search",
        "sLengthMenu": "Show: _MENU_ ",
        "sNext": "Next page"
    },

    'columns':[ //Column names
    ],
    'ajax': function (data, callback, settings) {
        var data_table = this;

        data_table.fnProcessingIndicator(true);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/getFeatures',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result){

                callback({
                    'aaData': result
                });

                data_table.fnProcessingIndicator(false);
            },
            failure: function(){
                data_table.fnProcessingIndicator(false);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Following is my method to add a new data row in this table and then auto-refresh

```
function createOrUpdateFeature(url) {
    $('#addNewRow').on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: $('#addNewRow').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            //dataType: 'script',
            success: function(data){
                data_table_api.ajax.reload();

           }
          });
    });
}
```

If I create a new row, the row gets created successfully and table is refreshed, displaying new row. Now if I immediately try to edit the newly created row, the create call happens again along with update call, and I get two rows with same data. Following is my edit call.

```
    $('#addNewRow').on('submit', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/updateFeature',
            data: $('#addNewRow').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(){
                data_table_api.ajax.reload();
            }
        });
    });
```

Please note, the form for add and edit is same. Also, if I remove the ajax.reload call, everything works fine but the auto-refresh does not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

You have attached submit handler to the same form `addNewRow` twice in your code for add and update the row.

```
$('#addNewRow').on('submit', function(e) { 
   // ... skipped ...
});
```

> **SOLUTION**

There could be many solutions based on your code structure and logic. The simplest one would be to detach the previous handler with the code below.

```
$('#addNewRow').off('submit');
$('#addNewRow').on('submit', function(e) { 
   // ... skipped ...
});
```